# Show new Page from a button in a Detail Page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I have a MasterDetailPage. I can add a page from my "Menu" and it is content inside the master page. When I want to do the same but with a button from my "FirstMasterPage" it show the Page but over the MasterDetailPage

I tried to create a new MasterPage but not showing nothing

This is the action of the button of one of my pages

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Pagina_Dos());
```

I also tried this, but showing nothing. Pagina_Master is my MasterDetailPage

```
  MasterDetailPage mdp = new Pagina_Master();
  mdp.Detail.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Pagina_Dos());
  mdp.IsPresented = false;
```

I want to show my content Page (Pagina_Dos) inside my Master Detail Page, when is clicked from the button. Because from the menu of course its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need a reference to the current MasterDetailPage

```
var mdp = (MasterDetailPage)App.Current.MainPage;
```

then you can use the Detail's Navigation property to push a new page

```
mdp.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new Pagina_Dos());
```